# Visual Studio Code internet error

Tags: visual-studio-code

So yesterday I was installing extensions and then when opening my laptop today I wanted to explore some more and got a message saying that I had an error and check my logs and this is what `[2018-06-07 10:51:07.049] [main] [info] update#setState idle
[2018-06-07 10:51:37.053] [main] [info] update#setState checking for updates
[2018-06-07 10:51:37.080] [main] [error] Error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
[2018-06-07 10:51:37.080] [main] [info] update#setState idle`

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Make sure your internet works because in my VSCode it works fine. https://snag.gy/wqsT63.jpg

Comment: Well my internet works and I posted the message with the machine that uses visual studio code so idk what's happening. The issue is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to fix it by doing the following command in my terminal (I'm using parrot security Os)

`dpkg-reconfigure code`